# ヘルプセンターの "Why was I suspended from the Review Queues? " を翻訳したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターに [Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions)  というページが追加されたようなので、こちらを翻訳したいです。

Answer (score 3):

ドラフトとしてどうぞお使いくださいませ m_ _m。直接編集よろしくお願いいたします！

---

### レビューキューが停止されたのはなぜ？

*レビューキューの概要やその仕組みについては、[こちらのページ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/314875)をご覧ください。*

レビューの一時停止とはペナルティではなくレビュー権限の一時的な保留です。正しくレビューする方法について学ぶ時間を得ることを目的としています。不十分なレビューは、コミュニティやサイトのコンテンツに悪影響を与えてしまいます。複数のタスクで誤ったアクションを取った場合、レビュー権限が一時的に停止され、この期間中はレビューキューにアクセスできなくなります。

レビューが停止されると、レビューキューナビゲーションドロップダウンに停止メッセージが表示されます。さらなる詳細については、[レビューキューダッシュボード](/review)とキューで確認できます。このメッセージは停止期間が終わるまで表示されます。

[image]

サイトへのアクセスの合い間にレビューが停止されることもあります。停止期間が終わった後であってもレビュー停止が発生したことは通知されます。メッセージを確認して承認すると通知は破棄されます。

#### レビューが停止されている間はどうすればいいですか？

停止のお知らせをよくお読みください。より適切なアクションが行えるよう、レビュー停止に至ったタスクを見直してください。そして停止の際に提供されるリソースリンクを確認してください。停止中であっても各キューの統計ページと履歴ページへはアクセスが可能です。停止に至ったレビュータスクについて質問がある場合は[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)に質問を投稿し、`[review-suspension]` タグを使用してください。投稿には必ず次の情報を含めてください：

- 停止の原因となったレビューへのリンク
- あなたが取ったアクションについての説明（停止が間違っていると感じる場合は特に重要です）
- どれが正しい選択がだったのか、その理由を理解したいという旨のリクエスト

今後は、もう少し時間をかけて見直し、十分な注意を払いながら各タスクを行うようにしてください。何が正しいアクションであるのかがわからない場合には「スキップ」機能を利用して他の誰かにレビューを処理してもらうようにしましょう。

Comment: スクリーンショットを日本語に変更できないか、CMのニックさんに依頼済みです。 (変更可能かどうか不明ですが...。)